# Converting JSON to DynaTree Object

Tags: javascript, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I have following data Structure which I want to use in data structure given in Dyntree Format:

```
[
  {
    title: "my Title",
    isFolder: "true",
    key: 1
  }
]
```

I am setting above data structure as STRING in a JS variable.

When I set this value as a javascript variable, it gives error of **Invalid Type**

[DynTree format](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-api.html) is given below;

```
 var fakeJsonResult = [
          { title: 'Lazy node 1', isLazy: true },
          { title: 'Simple node 2', select: true }
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple if you want to create a dynatree from the object you mentioned simply do this

```
var children = [
  {
    title: "my Title",
    isFolder: "true",
    key: 1
  }
];

$('#tree').dynatree({

   children : children

});
```